# Make Flash CS5 publish for Flash Player 10.1

Tags: flash, flex4, flash-cs5

I'm compiling a swf using Flex 4.1 SDK that loads another swf that is created by a designer using Flash CS5.  The 4.1 swf throws an error, "VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of removeChildBridge in mx.managers.SystemManagerProxy."  A few people around the web have said that they had this same error when their 4.1 swfs were loading swfs compiled by earlier versions of Flex.  The solution is to recompile the loaded swfs using the latest version of Flex.  So, I'm guessing that I simply need to get Flash CS5 to publish for Flash Player 10.1.  I've updated CS5, but still don't have the option to publish for the latest player.  How can I configure Flash to publish for Flash Player 10.1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to deal with the error you're getting, but I can tell you changing the publish settings in CS5 is not the answer. Flash player 10.1 was released recently, but the newest version of SWF content is still 10. So even with the authoring tool updated to understand the new APIs, for publish settings 10 is still the current version.

Comment: So you're saying that despite the player supporting new features, Flash CS5 cannot take advantage of those features, but FlashBuilder can because we can specify which SDK to use?

Comment: No, all I'm saying is that Flash CS5 doesn't need to change any publish settings to take advantage of the new features. For example, Accelerometer APIs were not part of Flash CS4 or Flash Player 10, and are newly supported by CS5 and FP10.1. So if you publish to "version 10" from CS4 you can't use them, and if you publish from CS5 you can. But in either case, the version tag of your SWF is the same. Essentially, the player doesn't need to be able to distinguish between a v10 SWF made from CS4 and one made in CS5, so they have the same options for publish settings.

Comment: You can also look at it this way: FP10.1 and Flash authoring CS5 accompany one another - 10.1 was released a bit later, but CS5 supported it out of the box. Flex authoring is out of cycle with flash, so Flex needed the 4.1 update since FP10.1 was not fully baked when 4.0 came out. That's why there's no similar update for CS5 to take advantage of FP10.1.